# Add static .a library in QtCreator

Tags: c++, g++, qt-creator

I want to use functionality of a math library ALGLIB and it's offered in .h and .cpp files. So I build it and added all the .o files to `alglib.a`. I copied it to my source directory and added these lines to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/ALGLIB/cpp/src
LIBS += -Lalglib
```

Well - I still get those "undefined reference to ..." errors when trying to build.

Comment: Did you run make clean, run qmake, build all?

Comment: May be you should also add PRE_TARGETDEPS += alglib.a to your pro file.

Comment: @tzunghaor: I deleted the build directory a few times and build again...  @Nejat: Now it says `No rule to make target `alglib.a', needed by `perlin_gen'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-L` sets a directory in which the linker should search for libraries.

`-l` sets a library file to link in the following way: `-lalglib` will look for a file named **libalglib.a** in all directories that are set with `-L`

Adding a file to `LIBS` without anything will link that exact file.

So either:

```
LIBS += alglib.a
```

or, provided that the alglib file name is **libalglib.a**:

```
LIBS += -Lalglib-directory -lalglib
```